# How to apply a function to each entry of a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have to store the log likelihood of some densities in a matrix, as follows:

```
Matrix.logLik 
            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,]     0.00000    0.0000    0.0000   0.0000    0
[2,]   -34.41018    0.0000    0.0000   0.0000    0
[3,] -2275.14867 -765.8642    0.0000   0.0000    0
[4,]    64.96982  264.7709 -256.1461   0.0000    0
[5,]   358.17822  260.1582  427.3490 363.2247    0
```

I would like to apply AIC function.

```
AIC.log <- function(x,y=2){
  -2*x+2*y
}
```

where `x` is the log likelihood value (the entries of the `Matrix.loglik`) and `y` is number of parameters. Then, I would like to store the result in a lower triangular matrix similar to `Matrix.loglik`.

Thank you for all answer. However, my matrix must stay lower triangular matrix. That is the zeros entries in my matrix must still zeros.

I try both answer and got this:

```
              [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
    [1,]    4.00000    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000    4
    [2,]   72.82036    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000    4
    [3,] 4554.29734 1535.7284    4.0000    4.0000    4
    [4,] -125.93964 -525.5418  516.2922    4.0000    4
    [5,] -712.35644 -516.3164 -850.6980 -722.4494    4
```

This is not what I should get.

number `4` must be zero. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can multiply by `lower.tri` to get desired result:

Matrix.logLik <- c(
      0.00000,    0.0000,    0.0000,   0.0000,    0,
     34.41018,    0.0000,    0.0000,   0.0000,    0,
  -2275.14867, -765.8642,    0.0000,   0.0000,    0,
     64.96982,  264.7709, -256.1461,   0.0000,    0,
    358.17822,  260.1582,  427.3490, 363.2247,    0)

Matrix.logLik <- matrix(Matrix.logLik, nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)


AIC.log <- function(x, y = 2){
  -2 * x + 2 * y
}


AIC.log(Matrix.logLik) * lower.tri(Matrix.logLik)

#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0.00000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0
#[2,]  -64.82036    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0
#[3,] 4554.29734 1535.7284    0.0000    0.0000    0
#[4,] -125.93964 -525.5418  516.2922    0.0000    0
#[5,] -712.35644 -516.3164 -850.6980 -722.4494    0
```

Another way to do it is to modify `AIC.log` function:

```
AIC.log <- function(x, y = 2){
  m <- -2 * x + 2 * y
  lower.tri(m) * m
}

AIC.log(Matrix.logLik)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes this is what I really want.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is vectorised, so you don't need any *apply implicit looping.

```
out <- Matrix.loglik
out[] <- AIC.log(Matrix.loglik)
lower.tri(out)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. However, the answer will not be lower.tri. please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks so much for both answers, I know now to transfer my output to what I want. I should use,  
`out[upper.tri(out, diag = T)] <- 0`

Answer (score 1):

`apply( Matrix.loglik , 1:2 , AIC.log )`

The second argument (`1:2`) determines the margin to apply the function over. `1:2` means apply the function over the first (rows) to the second (columns) margins of the matrix. If you had an array of three dimensions:

```
x <- array( rep(1:9,each=2) , dim = c(2,2,3) )
x
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    1    2
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    4
#[2,]    3    4
#
#, , 3
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    6
#[2,]    5    6
```

If you wanted to get the mean of the columns for each of the third dimensions you would apply across the second and third dimensions like so:

```
apply( x , c(2,3) , mean )
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    5
#[2,]    2    4    6
```

This can be extended to a matrix of any dimension.

Comment: `AIC.log(Matrix.logLik)` and `apply(Matrix.logLik, 1:2, AIC.log)` give the same result

Comment: @Simon thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate it. However, please note that, I need the matrix to still as upper triangular matrix. I tried you code but I dot number in the upper entries which must stay zeros. Could you please see the edit.

Comment: `apply( Matrix.loglik , 1:2 , AIC.log )` wont alter the dimensions of the matrix. Not sure what you are doing?